# How to use Lambda to call a method from a Jar (placed in S3)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Hi I have a use case where I want to call a method from a jar file (placed in S3) from an AWS lambda function. I also want to automate this process to execute at regular interval. How can i do it?

Comment: Are you expecting the call to be dynamic, so if you update the jar in S3, next time you call the lambda function it uses the updated jar? Or are you expecting to build the lambda function once and the method in the S3 jar doesn't get updated in Lambda unless you rebuild?

Comment: Download from S3 to '/tmp' and use it from there?

Comment: Jar in S3 will not be updated frequently. It will may be updated once in few months. I want to build lambda function once, which will keep calling same method in jar & regular interval & this call should be dynamic.

Comment: @AniketThakur - I didnt understand what do you mean. I want to run a processing job in Cloud. Jar file in S3 bucket does that processing & this jar file access some other files in another S3 bucket as well.

Comment: @user5402945 As per my understanding you cannot execute jar directly from S3. You can zip all contents you want download it to /tmp directory of lambda and then run the jar.